# confused with nodejs and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

i read many articles and posts about integrating nodeJS & angular, i don't understand at all. i tried to create the `server.js`, `mainController` and `index.html`, the server runs well but angular is not working. i've been stuck with this for one week and i can't solve it.

here is my `server.js` :

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var routes = require('./routes/routes');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/application')); //static path
routes(app);

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/application/views/index.html")
    //res.sendFile('./views/index.html');
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('server started on: ' + port);
```

here is the `mainController.js` :

```
var app = angular.module('server',[]);

// App controller
app.controller('appController', ['$scope','dataServ', function($scope, Data) {

    $scope.greetings = "hello words";

    Data.get()
        .success(function(resp) {
            $scope.greetings = resp;
        });
}]);
```

and this is my `index.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mainController">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing Web</title>

    <!-- LOAD JS -->
    <script src="../lib/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../controllers/mainController.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="appController">
        {{greetings}}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

here is my folder structure if needed :

> - application
>     -- controllers
>     --- mainController.js
>     -- lib
>     --- js
>     ---- angular.min.js
>     -- views
>     --- index.html
> - routes
> - server.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index.html, replace the `ng-app="mainController"` with `ng-app="server"` as it expects the main module name.

Comment: okay thankyou, but i got error about injector. do u know how to solve it?

Comment: The problem is in line `app.controller` where you are injecting `dataServ` service but later specified as `Data`. Replace 'Data` with `dataServ`